# Contar registros agrupados

Tags: mysql, group-by

Tengo una consulta que cuenta la cantidad de autores registrados en cada país. Ahora necesito también contar la cantidad de países que tengan cierto número de autores. Toda la información se extrae de una tabla. La consulta inicial es la siguiente.

```
mysql> SELECT country, COUNT(*)
    -> FROM author
    -> GROUP BY country;
+-----------+----------+
| country   | COUNT(*) |
+-----------+----------+
| Australia |        2 | 
| Brazil    |        1 | 
| Canada    |        2 | 
| Germany   |        1 | 
| India     |        1 | 
| UK        |        4 | 
| USA       |        4 | 
+-----------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

La idea es realizar una consulta que me de el siguiente resultado:

```
   | COUNT(country)  | COUNT(*) |
    +-----------+----------+
    | 3         |        1 | 
    | 2         |        2 | 
    | 2         |        4 | 

    +-----------+----------+
```

Donde la primera columna hace un conteo de la cantidad de países que tienen el número de autores que se ve en la columna derecha.

Ejemplos:

Brazil, Alemania e India (3) tienen (1) autor registrado.
Australia y Canada (2) tienen (2) autores registrados.
UK y USA (2) tienen (4) autores registrados.

Agradezco cualquier pista que puedan darme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo con una subconsulta:

```
SELECT Cantidad,
       COUNT(*)
       FROM (SELECT country, 
                    COUNT(*) as Cantidad
                    FROM author
                    GROUP BY country
       )
       GROUP BY Cantidad;
```

Tu consulta original, encapsulada en una subconsulta funciona como una tabla más, que agrupamos por cada cantidad y simplemente contamos ocurrencias de estas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, Patricio. Es justo lo que necesito y funciona perfectamente. Saludos.

Comment: @patricio-moracho Esa práctica de poner el cuerpo de la consulta después del `SELECT`  es personal o de algún tipo de estilo específico? Porque normalmente yo pongo tanto `SELECT`, `FROM`, `GROUP BY`, `JOIN`, `WHERE`, etc, hasta la izquierda y todo lo demás lo tabulo, columnas, subqueries, condiciones.

Comment: @Marco, es una forma a la que me acostumbre en parte producto de un estándar laboral que ya lo adopté como natural. Es cosmética, no creo que una forma u otra sea mejor.